# regular expression harming <br /> , embedded objects and iframes

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i found this great code to linkify plain text to links...

```
function text_to_link(inputText)
            {
                /*var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
                return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");*/

                var replaceText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;

                //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
                replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
                var replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

                //URLs starting with www. (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above)
                replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
                replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

                //Change email addresses to mailto:: links
                replacePattern3 = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;
                replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

                return replacedText;
    }
```

now the code is great but it is harming the embedded objects and iframes ...

```
 <object width="300" height="182"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/xVaBIF1LnwY?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/xVaBIF1LnwY?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340"></embed></object>
```

It also eats up all the br / (line breaks) in the text...

The sample page [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org)

can we just code it to leave all the text that is inside "object and object" or "iframe and iframe"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an standard solution to this:

1. First "encode" occurances of **inputText** inside object and iframe tags so that http|ftp|www|@. This way these sequences are not replaced in step 2.
2. Do the replacement as in the original function.
3. Now "decode" the occurances of  http|ftp|www|@ back.

Jakub

Answer (score 0):

i could somehow use this... but not a good solution...

```
     function text_to_link(inputText)
            {

                var object_text = new Array();
                var oi = 0;

                while ( inputText.indexOf('<object') >= 0)
                {
                    var si = inputText.indexOf('<object');
                    var ei = inputText.indexOf('</object>');
                    object_text[oi] = inputText.substring(si,ei+9);

                    inputText = inputText.replace(object_text[oi] , '[ob_service]');
                    oi ++;
                }

                var iframe_text = new Array();
                var ii = 0;
                while ( inputText.indexOf('<iframe') >= 0)
                {
                    var si = inputText.indexOf('<iframe');
                    var ei = inputText.indexOf('</iframe>');
                    iframe_text[ii] = inputText.substring(si,ei+9);

                    inputText = inputText.replace(iframe_text[ii] , '[if_service]');
                    ii ++;
                }

                var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
                inputText = inputText.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");



                oi =0;
                while (inputText.indexOf('[ob_service]') >= 0)
                {
                    inputText = inputText.replace('[ob_service]' , object_text[oi]);
                    oi ++;
                }

                ii =0;
                while (inputText.indexOf('[if_service]') >= 0)
                {
                    inputText = inputText.replace('[if_service]' , iframe_text[ii]);
                    ii ++;
                }


                return inputText;

            }
```

Please anyone knowing regular expressions do something good...

Thanks